# How to back-prop in a split net

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a case where I split my net and need to figure out back-prop.

The net goes like this:

```
                         /-- one-type-of-net-with-its-own-loss
common_couple_of_layers--
                         \-- another-type-of-net-with-its-own-loss
```

- Would I just add_to_collection, calculate gradients and update?
- Or do I need to rescale somehow at that point, where the two nets
  split (i.e. where the gradients "reunite")?
- Or normalize?
- Or...?
- Or is tensorflow doing this automatically when adding to the
  losses-collection?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the "losses collection" (e.g. via [`tf.contrib.losses.add_loss()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.losses.html#add_loss) or [`tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES, ...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#add_to_collection), you can use [`tf.contrib.losses.get_total_loss()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.losses.html#get_total_loss) to get a single loss value that can be passed to a standard TensorFlow [`tf.train.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer) subclass.
TensorFlow will derive the appropriate back-prop computation for your split network.

Comment: Thx! Also, would you mind posting your reply also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38783726/how-to-handle-gradients-when-training-two-sub-graphs-simultaneously ? Could award the bounty :)